# Looker Custom Iframe embedded events

Tags: javascript, iframe, looker

I'm using looker for a table visualisation.

I need the embedded iframe to communicate with parent window.
I'm using [embedded Iframe events](https://discourse.looker.com/t/javascript-embedded-iframe-events/2298) for some visualisations. And I'm receiving the default events

But I'm need to create and broadcast my own events.
For example, one cell in the table should broadcast `user:clicked:icon` which the parent window can than act upon.

Tried several methods through the LookML interface on the dimensions that I'm using (html, action etc) to even get something like `page:changed` to trigger, but with no success

**Update**
Found a current work around.  Using an existing action (`page:changed`) on an `html` created dimension (`a` tag).  I was able to intercept a navigation and accomplish some communication between the parent wrapper and looker iframe